# Generate all possible tuples combinations of given size for given range of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have 3 parameters: a range, size of n-element tuples (actually it might also be a list) and   possible combinations (without or with repetition). I want to get all the possible combinations of the numbers from the range.

So for example:

- Range a..b = 1..5
- size of tuple s=2
- without repetitions

  the result would be:

  (1, 1)(1, 2)(1, 3)(1, 4)(1, 5) 
  (2, 1)(2, 2)(2, 3)(2, 4)(2, 5)
  (3, 1)(3, 2)(3, 3)(3, 4)(3, 5)
  (4, 1)(4, 2)(4, 3)(4, 4)(4, 5)
  (5, 1)(5, 2)(5, 3)(5, 4)(5, 5)

With repetitions there would be of course much more tuples.

**It can be done iteratively obviously, but what would be the more pythonic and elegant way of achieving this task (maybe additional tools)?**

Comment: You say your example result is without repetitions, but it contains `(1, 1)`, `(2, 2)`, etc. It also has `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`, so that's not the definition of repetitions you're using. What would the version *with* repetitions look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With repetitions:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(1, 6), repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Without repetitions:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations(range(1, 6), 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)]
```